# SPARQL fetching yago rdf:type

Tags: types, sparql

I am using the following query to fetch all `rdf:type` associated with `wikiPageDisambiguates`  of term `Federer`. But the query returns only types which are in dbpedia-owl. But when I open the URI, there are other `rdf:type` associated, like : http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/SwissMaleTennisPlayers, etc. But in the query results I don't get all the `rdf:type`.

Query :

```
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/> 
select * 
where { 
        ?LandingURI rdfs:label ?term.
        ?LandingURI <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates> ?disambiguates .
        ?disambiguates rdf:type ?category .
        filter((?term ="Federer (disambiguation)"@en))
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Which URI do you open?

Comment: Somehow i get the link : http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer from dbpedia for the term Federer. Now for this link i want to get all the rdf:type for this link. My query only returns dbpedia-owl types,not others.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  What types aren't you getting?  E.g,. when I run your query, I **do** see `http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/SwissMaleTennisPlayers` in the results.